# GraphQL resolver for type element having many to many relationship

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm setting up a GraphQL Apollo Server, and want to define a resolver for an object type that has an element containing an array of data based on a many to many relationship.

I have a `Measurement` object that is associated to an `Activity` object with a many to many relationship:

```
Measurement.belongsToMany(Activity, {
    as: 'activity',
    through: 'activity_measurement_entries',
    underscored: true
});
Activity.belongsToMany(Measurement, {
    as: 'measurements',
    through: 'activity_measurement_entries',
    underscored: true
});
```

A resolver query works fine for the `getActivities` query when `Measurement` is included directly in the query like this:

```
getActivities: async (parent, args, { models }) => {
    const activities = await models.Activity.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: models.Measurement,
            as: 'measurements',
        }],
    });
    return activities;
},
```

An `activity_measurement` table is generated automatically through Sequelize which contains `activity_id` and `measurement_id`.

I would like to define a resolver for the `measurements` field on `Activity` like below, but I'm not sure how to structure the where clause and what is passed in the parent parameter with the many to many relationship table in the middle (assume a similar `getActivities` query is used to get all `Activities` and the associated measurements but no input parameter to the query):

```
Activity: {
    measurements: (parent, args, { models }) => models.Measurement.findAll({
      where: {
        ????
      },
    }),
},
```

For a query that attempts to get all the `Activities` when the `Activity` type is defined like this:

```
getActivities: async (parent, args, { models }) => 
    models.ActivityEntry.findAll()
```

If there is no where clause in the resolver for the `measurements` field of the `Activity` type then every measurement is returned under every `Activity` (instead of just the measurements associated through the `activity_measurement` table).

I am trying to figure out how to get only the measurements associated with the Activity to be returned when using the separate Activity type definition with a measurements element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent value that's passed to the resolver reflects the value that was returned in the parent field's resolver. In this case, for the `measurements` field, the parent field is `getActivities`. You're returning an array of Activity model instances in `getActivities`, so the parent value passed to the `measurements` field resolver will also be an instance of your `Activity` model.

That means you can do something like:

```
Activity: {
  measurements: (activity, args, { models }) => activity.getMeasurements(),
},
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  This worked, but something I discovered is that this method actually takes over twice as long to return the result as when the includes were in a single resolver so not sure which approach I'll take yet.  Also, due to a linter issue it was actually simplified to this: Activity: {
  measurements: activity => activity.getMeasurements(),
  },